# How are these limits calculated?

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I am reading Hoffman's Contemporary Calculus. I do not understand where $2$ and $3$ came from in the textbook's solution to this problem in Chapter 1.4 Formal Definition of Limit - Problem # 19, page 11:
http://scidiv.bellevuecollege.edu/dh/Calculus_all/Calculus_all.html
[image]

The solution below states that the limit is 2 if $$x>2$$, while the limit is 3 if $$x<2$$  See 'Chapter 1 Odd Answers' in the above link.

From what I understand by looking at the graph, it should be $3$ and $4$, respectively.

[image]

Comment: I agree with you, in that the limits should be 3 and 4 respectively.

Comment: There is an error in the book – the picture does not agree with the description of $f$. According to the textual definition, $f$ is not defined at $2$, while according to the graph $f(2)=4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right indeed, there must be a typo and we have that

$$\lim_{x\to2^+} f(x)=3\quad \lim_{x\to2^-} f(x)=4$$

then

$$\lim_{x\to2} f(x)$$

doesn't exist.